# Naming a datafile with spaces in the name

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces, datafile, oracle-asm

I would like to know if there could be a problem when naming a datafile with spaces in the name, I have an Oracle 11gR2 database, using ASM as storage, a datafile was created, belonging to an application's tablespace, with a name that contains spaces:
"+DATA/oracl/data/**my new dtf**"
that is, the name of the tablespace is: **my new dtf**, it was created without problems, but I have doubts that it could cause a conflict.

Comment: It could potentially cause problems if you ever need to refer to the filename in a command line. Depending on your operating system and the command you might need to escape the spaces, or use quotes around the filename to make sure it is recognized correctly. In my experience (almost 30 years with Oracle, and 12+ years with ASM now), when using ASM in particular, I always found it easiest/best to let Oracle name all of the files automatically rather than force them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, could you give me an example of how it would be to refer specifically to the file? In the next few days I'm going to change the name, but now I can't, I would have to wait for this, so apparently it doesn't affect the normal functioning of the system at all unless I have to do some specific and manual work with those files ... is that so?

Comment: You already know (now) not to name files with spaces in the names. I'd also point out that you should not use database object names (like oh, say, tablespace names) with spaces.  (and along with that, you should not create object names with mixed case names. Do not enclose object names with double spaces when you create them, thus allowing oracle to default the names to upper-case but treating them as case IN-sensitive.)